# Is there a way to display the value together with the label on the legend in C3js pie chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, c3.js

I am using c3js to render charts in my project and I am wondering if there is a way to display the value on the legend together with the label.
Like,

```
 Office 40%
 Home   20%
 Drive  30%
 Other  10%
```

JSFiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/wscfujgg

Comment: Show us your code. A JSFiddle demo would be ideal.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/wscfujgg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide custom legends like this in c3js

```
d3.select('#chart').insert('div', '.chart').attr('class', 'legend').selectAll('span')
    .data(['Office', 'School', 'Water', 'Work'])
  .enter().append('div')
    .attr('data-id', function (id) { return id; })
    .html(function (id) {  return  getDataValue(id); })
    .each(function (id) {
        d3.select(this).style('background-color', chart.color(id));
    })
    .on('mouseover', function (id) {
        chart.focus(id);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (id) {
        chart.revert();
    })
    .on('click', function (id) {
        chart.toggle(id);
    });
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/6j4kecqq/2/):

Comment: I need when mouse over on legend show the tool tip also. is this possible?